SSH permission denied via Windows PowerShell
I want to log into a Ubuntu server from my Windows machine. When I use PowerShell, permission is denied.
PS C:\Users\sebastian> ssh seb@135.181.180.30
seb@135.181.180.30's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
seb@135.181.180.30's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
seb@135.181.180.30's password:
seb@135.181.180.30: Permission denied (publickey,password).
PS C:\Users\sebastian>

When I use the Ubuntu sub-system, it works as expected.
seb@DESKTOP-U20EMGM:~$ ssh seb@135.181.108.30
seb@135.181.108.30's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-31-generic aarch64)

This behavior began when I added public keys to the authorized_keys file. I have checked the permissions, but they seem fine:
seb@ubuntu-4gb-hel1-1:~/.ssh$ ls -la
total 12
drwx------ 2 seb seb 4096 May 20 04:45 .
drwxr-x--- 9 seb seb 4096 May 19 15:14 ..
-rw------- 1 seb seb 2109 May 20 04:45 authorized_keys 

I suspect this maybe an issue with Windows PowerShell. Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Log on to the server and look in the authentication log. You'll see the reason for the failures there

to see what's happens you can launch ssh with --vvv option and it will be more verbose.

Does your password contain non-ASCII or other characters that PS might interpret as special?


PS C:\Users\sebastian> ssh seb@135.181.180.30

Uses a different set of config files / looks for keys in a different place (C:\Users\sebastian\.ssh\*) than your Ubuntu installation. Copy the files from \\wsl$\ubuntu\home\sebastion\ to C:\Users\sebastian\.ssh\

Thanks, I tried that. That was part of the solution, but didn't get me all the way. The solution involved some extensive research about PowerShell and OpenSSH, several re-installs and reconfigurations. This whole experience really makes me reconsider my choice of Windows as a developer platform.

@Sebastian so what did get you all the way. Please consider adding your own answer too, to help others you might also encounter this issue

@ChrisDavies: I did below, should I mark my answer as the solution even though I'm not exactly sure which part of it solved the problem?

I solved this with the help of symcbean's answer.I'm not exactly sure which of the steps below did it, but now it's working. Since I'm on a Windows system, trying to SSH into Ubuntu, I did the following:

Uninstall Windows PowerShell
Uninstall OpenSSH
Reinstall PowerShell
Reinsall OpenSSH via the PowerShell (not the GUI, see the Microsoft docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse?tabs=powershell)


It's happening because SSH is not found in your system. An easy and simple method to fix this is to install git on your system, and while installing it you have to select Openssh and then install it.
But if you already have git installed on your system, uninstall it and then re-install it.
This worked for me. Hopefully, it will also work for you.
